# Polynomials (abstract algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find all units of $S$, where $S$ is the set of polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ whose coefficient of $x$ is $0$.
I think the units are $\mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$. Is that correct?

Comment: What is $Q$? Do you mean the rational numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Q means the set of rational numbers

Comment: @TheChaz: That was an edit made after Brandon's comment.

Comment: "units of $S$, where $S$ is the set of ..." is a somewhat unusual use of the terminology -- usually in "units *of* $X$", $X$ is a ring; otherwise one would say something like "the units of $\mathbb Q[x]$ that lie in $S$". But it so happens that $S$ is indeed a ring, so you could say "Find all units of $S$, where $S$ is the ring of ...".

Comment: so, what are the units then?

Comment: @max: You're right that the units are $\mathbb Q\setminus \{0\}$ -- but note the direction of the slash; "$/$" has a _different_ meaning in algebra. Now can you start a proof why this is true? We'll help you fill in the gaps where you get into trouble.

Comment: I think I got the proof. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

We have $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $S=\mathbb{Q}[x^2,x^3]$.  Since $U(R)=\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}\subseteq S$, it follows that $U(S)=\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Let $\rm\:T = \mathbb Q[x].\:$ By $\rm\:U(T) = U(\mathbb Q)\:$ and unit inheritance $\rm\:R\subset R'\:\Rightarrow\:U(R)\subset U(R')\:$ follows

$$\rm\: \mathbb Q\subset S\subset T\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ U(\mathbb Q) \subset U(S) \subset U(T)\subset U(\mathbb Q)\:\ \Rightarrow\ \ U(\mathbb Q) = U(S) = U(T) $$